# How to use JNI in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

I have a JAR library that i need to use in a Unity project but i have never used JAR before,

i couldn't get JNI to work correctly 
here is a simple code which outputs 0 but probably should return the correct hashcode of the java string??

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        AndroidJNIHelper.debug = true;
        using (AndroidJavaObject jc = new 
    AndroidJavaObject("java.lang.String","test"))
        {
            int a = jc.CallStatic<int>("hashCode");
            Debug.Log(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `hashCode` is not a static function, so `CallStatic` seems incorrect. Try `Call` instead.

Comment: @Michael still 0 !

Comment: Could it be beaucse i run editor player?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that i was using the editor after moving to android it worked perfectly .